# extends page directive not working

Tags: java, jsp

Hi i am checking page directives but extends page directive is not working.
The below my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page extends="javapackage.TestClass" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>Hai
<% out.println(show()); %>
</body>
</html>
```

and my class is

```
package javapackage;

public class TestClass {
  public String show(){
      return "Welcome Prasad";
 }
}
```

it gives me 500 error
exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jsp.first_jsp cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:177)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause 

  java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jsp.first_jsp cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

even i tried with class which extends HttpServlet but of no use .So any one please help me.I am using Tomcat 7
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the JSP specification, particularly section JSP.11.2.4 which sets out a number of requirements for the super class you use with extends and none of which are met by the super class in your question.

> ...the provided superclass:
>
> - Implements HttpJspPage if the protocol is HTTP, or JspPage otherwise.
> - All of the methods in the Servlet interface are declared final.
>
> Additionally, it is the responsibility of the JSP page author that the provided
>   superclass satisfies:
>
> - The service method of the servlet API invokes the _jspService method.
> - The init(ServletConfig) method stores the configuration, makes it available via
>     getServletConfig, then invokes jspInit.
> - The destroy method invokes jspDestroy.