# How page directive "extend" in jsp works?

Tags: jsp-tags, directive

A jsp file when gets compiled to a java class, it's already extending a servlet. Again, if we put an extend page directive [i.e. `<%@ page extends="..." %>`], then how does it behave? How the class can extend 2 different classes??

Comment: No answer!! Is this question not clear?

Comment: Well in all my years of developing JSPs I have never used this directive however, I would guess that the class you specify must itself inherit from HttpServlet so, therefore, no multiple inheritance.

Comment: Here's you answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114432/extends-page-directive-not-working