# How to use @page extends in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am trying to develop a code using @page extends attribute, but its showing the page compilation error.
please tell me how can i use @page extends attribute in this scenario.

```
<%@page import="com.learning.core.java.PageDirectiveTest"%>
<%@page extends="com.learning.core.java.PageDirectiveTest" %>

<%! PageDirectiveTest test = new PageDirectiveTest(); %>
Result is: <%=test.getRandomNumber() %>
```

Comment: You don't. You are misunderstanding the fundamentals of JSP.

Comment: May be, but how can i use this tag?
Any example

Answer (score 0):

This attribute will make sure that while converting your jsp into servlet,generated servlet extends the class defined by you.

This attribute is not quite popular among developers.It is reserved for vendors beacuse it can result in the fundamental changes how the page behaves.

### See Also

- [extends page directive not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26114432/extends-page-directive-not-working)